# How to force a variable initialized in dynamically loaded javascript to be visible to other (static) scripts

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, dynamically-generated

I have some code allowing audio libraries such as Audiolet.js and an application javascript file to be dynamically loaded into the browser and (ultimately) driven by user-supplied data. The idea is that such audio libraries should be exchangable by the user.

I see from the DOM inspector that although both the above files are correctly loaded, but neither appear to be accessed nor perhaps even accessible.

The application code was placed in a wrapper function in turn assigned to a global variable (sound_generator) previously initialised to null in a dedicated (static) header file elsewhere:

```
sound_generator = function () {
   // Audiolet application code
   function play_demo(){....}
   //    :         :         :
return {
    playDemo : function() {
        play_demo();
    },
    test : function() {
                    alert("yessss!");
            } 
}
};
```

Accessed from anywhere within the other, static code, sound_generator.test() provokes a

```
ReferenceError: sound_generator is not defined.
```

I tried making the function self-executing.

```
sound_generator = function () {
   // Audiolet application code
}();
```

--> again, ReferenceError: sound_generator is not defined.

I stripped away the trailing brackets and tried placing all this in an onload() statement:

```
window.onload=function(){
  sound_generator = function () {
     // Audiolet application code
  };
};
```

--> again, ReferenceError: sound_generator is not defined.

With debugging on, I tried otherwise pointless alternatives such as changing sound_generator into a function and, using

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", sound_generator, false);
```

watching for log output. No go.

Even tried equivalent jQuery approaches, but so far no improvement.

This is not a problem with asynchronous loading delays, and from behaviours elsewhere I have no reason to believe any globals are being instantiated after dynamic loading.

The dynamically loaded code is simply not being accessed. How might I force this code to be executed so that the global variable and embedded calls can be picked up by static scripts elsewhere in the single page application?

Comment: One thing you should look into is that the error says "sound_generator is not defined", as if your statement that "(sound_generator) previously initialised to null in a dedicated (static) header file elsewhere" weren't true. Even if the dynamic script weren't run, you should still be able to see the variable `sound_generator` and its null value.

Comment: I tried instantiating sound_generator directly where needed. Though it's dynamically loaded file is demonstrably present in the DOM and the DOM entry in every respect analagous to those of other, fully accessible (dynamically loaded) files, attempts at accessing it's code are failing. Strangely, this seems to suggest the problem lies within file itself, yet similar onload/ready directives are working elsewhere..

Comment: Maybe a naming conflict somewhere. The answer will probably hit me while sleeping.